# Poisson distribution Problem

Tags: probability

For a random variable x, let g(x) be given by $g(x)=E|X=m(x)|$, where m(x) is the median of X. Find g(x) for a Poisson random variable with mean 1.5

SO far if x is Poisson with $\lambda=1.5$ 
then
$m(x)=1$

$g(x)=E|X-1|=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}|x-1|*p(x=x)$

Don't know if I'm right ,but I'm stuck

Comment: I assume you mean $g(x) = \mathbb E[|X-m(x)|]$ (and not "$X=m(x)$")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a random variable, a real number $m$ is a median of $X$ if $\mathbb P(X\leqslant m)\geqslant\frac12$ and $\mathbb P(X\geqslant m)\geqslant\frac12$. Note that in general there need not be a unique median; consider for example a uniform distribution on $(0,1)\cup (2,3)$, for which any $m\in [1,2]$ is a median.

For a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda=\frac32$, we have 
$$\mathbb P(X\leqslant 1) = e^{-\frac32}\left(1 + \frac32\right) = \frac52 e^{-\frac32}\approx 0.557825>\frac12 $$
and 
$$\mathbb P(X\geqslant 1) = 1 - e^{-\frac32}\approx 0.77687>\frac12.$$
Further, $\mathbb P(X\leqslant 0)=e^{-\frac32}<\frac12$ and $\mathbb P(X\geqslant 2) = 1-\mathbb P(X\leqslant 1)<\frac12$, so $m=1$ is the unique median. Now, for nonnegative integers $k$ we have
$$
|k-1| = \begin{cases}
1,&k=0\\
0,&k=1\\
k-1,&k>1.
\end{cases}
$$
It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[|X-1|] &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty |k-1|\mathbb P(X=k)\\
&= \mathbb P(X=0) + \sum_{k=2}^\infty (k-1)\mathbb P(X=k)\\
&= e^{-\frac32} + \sum_{k=2}^\infty (k-1)e^{-\frac32}\frac{\left(\frac 32\right)^k}{k!}\\
&= e^{-\frac32}\left(1 + \sum_{k=2}^\infty k\frac{\left(\frac 32\right)^k}{k!} - \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac 32\right)^k}{k!}\right)\\
&= e^{-\frac32}\left(1 + \frac32\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac 32\right)^k}{k!} - \sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac 32\right)^k}{k!} \right)\\
&=e^{-\frac32}\left(1 + \frac32\left(e^{\frac32}-1\right) -\left(e^{\frac32} -1-\frac32 \right)\right)\\
&=e^{-\frac32}\left(2 + \frac12 e^{\frac32} \right)\\
&= \frac12 + 2 e^{-\frac32}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Your expression $\displaystyle g(x)=E|X-1|=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}|x-1|\times \Pr(X=x)$

can be rewritten as $\displaystyle (1-0)\times\Pr(X=0)+ \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}(x-1)\times \Pr(X=x)$

or $\displaystyle 2 \times (1-0)\times\Pr(X=0)+ \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}x\times \Pr(X=x)- \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}1\times \Pr(X=x)$

which is $\displaystyle 2 \times \Pr(X=0)+ E[X] -1$

and with $\lambda=\frac32$ this is  $2 e^{-3/2}+\dfrac12 \approx 0.94626.$